# JMeter access log sampler filter

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter to test real calls on a Tomcat server. How do I filter calls using the access log filter functions? For example, I do not want to run urls containing the parameter "system=filter".

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

1) Use a program like grep/sed/awk to strip out the calls you want to skip.
2) Create a custom logParser plugin or filter.

See the [manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access_Log_Sampler) for more info on this sampler, and for details on creating the parser or filter, you'll likely need to use the [mailing list](http://jmeter.apache.org/mail.html) to get additional specifics.